# How would I remove items from a List<T>?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of items.

The problem is the returned items (which I have no control over) return the same items THREE time.

So while the actual things that should be in the list are:

1. A
2. B
3. C

I get

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. A
5. B
6. C
7. A
8. B
9. C

How can I cleanly and easily remove the duplicates? Maybe count the items, divide by three and delete anything from X to list.Count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are 100% sure that you receive everything you need 3 times, then just

```
var newList = oldList.Take(oldList.Count / 3).ToList()
```

Comment: This worked. Since my items don't implement IEquality, this will have to do for now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 11):

The quickest, simplest thing to do is to *not* remove the items but run a distinct query

```
var distinctItems = list.Distinct();
```

If it's a must that you have a list, you can always append `.ToList()` to the call. If it's a must that you continue to work with the *same* list, then you'd just have to iterate over it and keep track of what you already have and remove any duplicates.

**Edit:** "But I'm working with a class"

If you have a list of a given class, to use Distinct you need to either (a) override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` inside your class so that appropriate equality comparisons can be made. If you do not have access to the source code (or simply don't want to override these methods for whatever reason), then you can (b) provide an `IEqualityComparer<YourClass>` implementation as an argument to the `Distinct` method. This will also allow you to specify the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations without having to modify the source of the actual class.

```
public class MyObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public bool Equals(MyObject a, MyObject b)
    {
        // code to determine equality, usually based on one or more properties
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObject a)
    {
        // code to generate hash code, usually based on a property
    }
}

// ...

var distinctItems = myList.Distinct(new MyObjectComparer());
```

Comment: if the correct sequence has, for example, two A's, they will be erroneously removed.

Comment: @Michael - ok, but that's not what the OP asked for: "How can I cleanly and easily remove the duplicates?"

Comment: This is strange. It seems the Distinct doesn't actually remove the items. The List of type of a Class I created, they're not simple primitives.

Comment: @Michael, the question does not indicate that to be the problem. If it is, then yes, it's a different requirement and a different solution.

Comment: @Sergio you can provide Distinct with an implementation of IEqualityComparer to indicate exactly how to determine whether your classes are duplicate with each other

Comment: The sample says what the OP means, he is not 100% correct in his formulations, but it is absolutely clear that he can have duplicates in the correct sequence. Moreover, as OP states above, `Distinct` does not work for reference classes other than `string`.

Comment: @Michael it's not clear as everyone came up with Distinct()... Also, distinct does work for reference classes other than string, you just need to pass in an equality comparer.

Comment: Thank you for your time guys. Trust me on this one, for this SPECIFIC case, it would be better to just count the items and delete based on the simple math formula. For the other 99.9% cases, I will use the IEquality.

Comment: @Dave: I am never ashamed to be cleverer than everyone, sorry.

Comment: If it has two A's, one will be removed, not both.

Comment: @yoda: Yes, the Distinct() solutions are much mare resistant against variations in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Linq has a Distinct() method which does exactly this. Or put the items in a HashSet if you want to avoid duplicated completely.

Comment: if the correct sequence has, for example, two A's, they will be erroneously removed.

Comment: In that case, just take the first N/3 elements of the list. You can also do that with LINQ: list.Take(list.Count / 3)

Comment: @Michael: If it has two A's, one will be removed, not both.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# 3 or up:

```
var newList = dupList.Distinct().ToList();
```

If not then sort the list and do the following:

```
var lastItem = null;
foreach( var item in dupList )
{
    if( item != lastItem )
    {
        newItems.Add(item);
    }

    lastItem = item;
}
```

Comment: if the correct sequence has, for example, two A's, they will be erroneously removed.

Comment: and your second approach applies that the elements' class must be IComparable or some custom sorting mechanism needs to be defined.

Comment: Yes, it does. You need to be able to compare them to be able to tell if they're duplicates. The alternative to sorting them is to check whether each object is in the newItems list, which is fine but slow, sorting speeds it up. On vs approx. On^2 (discounting sort time, obv.)

Answer (score 0):

you could simply create a new list and add items to it that are not already there.